# Show that $29 | N$ Problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $\frac{29}{25} x_1$ and $\frac{39}{50}x_2$ equal $N$ for some $x_1,x_2$. If $x_{1,2}$ are positive integers show that:
>
> $$29 | N,\space \text{and} \space 39 | N$$

So, $$29 | N \implies \frac{N}{29} = m \in \mathbb{N}$$

Similarly,

$$39 | N \implies \frac{N}{39} = j \in \mathbb{N}$$

Lets begin with the first one.

$$N \equiv 0 \pmod{29}$$

But I cannot go much further.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{29}{25}x_1=N\iff 25N=29x_1$.
Here $29$ divides RHS, so must divide LHS, but $(25,29)=1$, so $29\mid N$.

$\frac{39}{50}x_2=N\iff 50N=39x_2$.
Here $39$ divides RHS, so must divide LHS, but $(50,39)=1$, so $39\mid N$.

---

You can't begin with what you want to prove and continue using implications $\implies$ -- what you mean is $\iff$ (if and only if (iff)), which denotes equivalence of statements.

So, e.g., $29\mid N\iff \frac{N}{29}=m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: At the top, how does, 

$$25N = 29x_1$$ Imply that $29$ divides the RHS?

Comment: Definition: $a$ divides $b$ iff $b=ak$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. So $29$ divides $29x_1$ iff $29x_1=29k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, and this is trivially true, since $k=x_1\in\mathbb Z$. It is a trivial fact that $a\mid ab$ for any $a\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Lebes $29$ is simply one of the integers multiplied together. There is $29$ times $x_1$ (which too is an integer), and so $29$ divides $29x_1$. Denoted $29\mid 29x_1$.